# Want to skip CSS formating of nested Table in html

Tags: html, css

Here is HTML code:
even odd rows having different color.
I want in each row in one  there is a table which have to background as same as that row.
But table having inner class it take css format of outer class. how can I skip and gives Inner table background to as same as that row

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>My AngularJS App</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="PeopleCtrl">
    <button  ng-click="loadPeople()">Click me!!</button>
    <!--{{people.result}}-->
    <table class="outer">
      <tr>
        <th>customerId</th>
        <th>customerNum</th>
        <th>companyName</th>
        <th>address</th>
        <th>term</th>
        <th>status</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="person in people.result">
        <td>{{person.customerId}}</td>
        <td>{{person.customerNum}}</td>
        <td>{{person.companyName}}</td>
        <td>
          <table class="inner">
            <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in person.address">
              <td>{{key}}</td><td>{{value}}</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td>{{person.term}}</td>
        <td>{{person.status}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS :

```
.outer tr:nth-child(even)
{
  background: #CCC;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
.outer tr:nth-child(odd)
{
  background: #FFF;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reset the background of the nested child. Note you need to add `nth-child` in that selector too, to give it a higher specificity.

```css
.outer tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #CCC;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
.outer tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #FFF;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.outer tr:nth-child(odd) tr,
.outer tr:nth-child(even) tr {
  background: inherit;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>My AngularJS App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


  <div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="PeopleCtrl">
      <button ng-click="loadPeople()">Click me!!</button>
      <!--{{people.result}}-->
      <table class="outer">
        <tr>
          <th>customerId</th>
          <th>customerNum</th>
          <th>companyName</th>
          <th>address</th>
          <th>term</th>
          <th>status</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="person in people.result">
          <td>{{person.customerId}}</td>
          <td>{{person.customerNum}}</td>
          <td>{{person.companyName}}</td>
          <td>
            <table class="inner">
              <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in person.address">
                <td>{{key}}</td>
                <td>{{value}}</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
          <td>{{person.term}}</td>
          <td>{{person.status}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="person in people.result">
          <td>{{person.customerId}}</td>
          <td>{{person.customerNum}}</td>
          <td>{{person.companyName}}</td>
          <td>
            <table class="inner">
              <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in person.address">
                <td>{{key}}</td>
                <td>{{value}}</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
          <td>{{person.term}}</td>
          <td>{{person.status}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="person in people.result">
          <td>{{person.customerId}}</td>
          <td>{{person.customerNum}}</td>
          <td>{{person.companyName}}</td>
          <td>
            <table class="inner">
              <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in person.address">
                <td>{{key}}</td>
                <td>{{value}}</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
          <td>{{person.term}}</td>
          <td>{{person.status}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Great, It's Working very fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Simply provide the necessary styles to the `table` inside of the `tr`

```
.outer tr:nth-child(even),
.outer tr:nth-child(even) table    /* Added this line */
{
  background: #CCC;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
.outer tr:nth-child(odd),
.outer tr:nth-child(odd) table     /* Added this line */
{
  background: #FFF;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either specify immediate child `tr`s or override the background color of `tr`s within other `tr`s.

Method 1:

```
.outer > tr:nth-child(even)
{
  background: #CCC;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
.outer > tr:nth-child(odd)
{
  background: #FFF;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

Method 2:

```
.outer tr:nth-child(even)
{
  background: #CCC;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
.outer tr:nth-child(odd)
{
  background: #FFF;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
.outer tr tr
{
  background: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
.outer .inner tr:nth-child(even)
{
  background: #CCC;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
.outer tr:nth-child(odd)
{
  background: #FFF;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

Comment: It's not working for this code.
It is applying CSS to inner table.
But I want the whatever formatting comes to row it should be applied to whole inner table not for each row in the inner table